# Selenium - how to click on the button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am looking for the way to click on the button which is located in HTML this way:

```html
<button class="MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium MuiButtonBase-root  css-1rs4rtx" tabindex="0" type="button"> Zaloguj się<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span></button>
```

I tried a few ways to find this without any success.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Web credentials
username = "qwerty@gmail.com"
password = "qwerty"

# Initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")

# Head to login page
driver.get("https://tzgirls.app/login")

# Find username/email field and send the username itself to the input field
driver.find_element("id", "login_email").send_keys(username)

# Find password input field and insert password as well
driver.find_element("id", "login_password").send_keys(password)

#import time
#time.sleep(2)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Zaloguj się')]"))).click()
```

How can I do it?

Comment: element.click(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To login within the [website](https://tzgirls.app/login) filling up the *E-mail* and *Password* field and clicking on the <kbd>Zaloguj się</kbd> element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
driver.get("https://tzgirls.app/login")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.MuiButton-root.MuiButton-text.MuiButton-textPrimary.MuiButton-sizeMedium.MuiButton-textSizeMedium.MuiButtonBase-root"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#login_email"))).send_keys("Paulina@stackoverflow.com")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#login_password").send_keys("asdfg")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Zaloguj się']").click()
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: Paulina]

Comment: Please remove the actual credentials from shown code

Comment: @undetected Selenium Thank you! it is working! but please delete the email from the code.

Comment: @Paulina How about _Paulina@stackoverflow.com_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. `find_elements_by_xpath` is now deprecated, as well as all the rest of `find_elements_by*` methods.
2. `.css-1rs4rtx` is not a class name; this is a CSS Selector style.
3. `findElement` is Java style, etc.

Try using this:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.MuiButton-containedPrimary").click()
```

Probably it would be better to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` to click the element when it becomes clickable.
If so this can be done as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.MuiButton-containedPrimary"))).click()
```

Comment: now I get this error: "NameError: name 'By' is not defined"

Comment: See the updated answer.  you need this import: `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: I tried - "     93     if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     94         break
---> 95 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException: Message:   "

Comment: Not so clear what exactly you tried...

Comment: Can you share all your code and a link to page you working on?

Comment: Not here, inside the question, please make the code readable

Comment: credentials are wrong...

Comment: The text there is `Wyloguj się'

Comment: The logout button

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Wyloguj sie - logout. Zaloguj sie - login.

Comment: Ah, so you need the login button. I see.. Will update the answer shortly. Please remove the comment with actual credentials